# using NOT IN for multiple tables

Tags: sql, t-sql

How can I simplify multiple 'not in' queries? Is it efficient to use multiple subqueries: Not in (...) and Not in (..) and Not in (..)

I am using count (sorry forgot about that)

```
 Select count (VisitorID)

 from Company

 where VisitorID not in (select VisitorID from UserLog where ActionID = 2 )

 and VisitorID not in (select VisitorID from Supplies where productID = 4)
```

Comment: Can you give an idea of the tables size? What about the selectivity of the two sub-selects? One third, 1 in 100?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Select count (VisitorID)

from Company C
where
NOT EXISTS (select * from UserLog U where ActionID = 2 AND C.VisitorID  = U.VisitorID)
AND
NOT EXISTS (select * from Supplies S where productID = 4 AND S.VisitorID  = U.VisitorID)
```

Why NOT EXISTS?

- NOT IN: Any NULL VisitorID values in UserLog or Supplies means no match
- (LEFT JOIN): multiple output rows if many UserLog or Supplies per VisitorID. Needs DISTINCT which changes the plan

*Generally*, NOT EXISTS is the only correct option

Answer (score 2):

You could use a UNION for the id group

```
Select User

from Company

where VisitorID not in (
select VisitorID from UserLog where ActionID = 2 
UNION
select VisitorID from Supplies where productID = 4
)
```